# Flutter Ternary Operator inside a String doesn't work

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the ternary operator to avoid null values within my Text-Widgets.

If the variable is null, I would assume noData as value. But while debugging I noticed that ternary operator directly jumps out, without going to ELSE.

If the variable is not null, it works fine.

```
    String noData = "No data available";

.....

                  Text(
                    "Population:",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.values[4],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "${country.data.last.population != null ? country.data.last.population : noData}",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                    ),
                  ),

.....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the quotes around your default string `'noData'`.

You probably wanted to do:

```
Text('${country.data.last.population != null ? country.data.last.population : 'noData'}'),
```

But why not the simpler:

```
Text(country.data.last.population ?? 'noData'),
```

---

Simple example in answer to comment below:

```
void main() {
  String noData = "No data available";
  double value;
  print("${value != null ? value : noData}");     // No data available
  print("${value ?? noData}");                    // No data available
  value = 10.0;
  print("${value != null ? value : noData}");     // 10
  print("${value ?? noData}");                    // 10
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution. And noData is a variable, right. The strange thing is, that it still doesn't work. population is a double value and it's null. I had to define it as double to avoid JSON decoding problems. Even with ?? it still jumps out of the line without using the alternative variable / String

Comment: Weird, the problem must come from somewhere else. Are you sure `country.data.last.population` is `null` and not empty? Or, maybe `country.data.last` is `null`? In that case, you should maybe test `country.data.last?.population`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue with your data that is causing that error. It's not an issue with the Dart language. You can try out the below example on https://dartpad.dev/ where I am, like you, getting a `String` value from a inside a object and checking if it's null. It works in both cases:

```
void main() {
  Person person1 = Person(name: 'John', age: 35);
  Person person2 = Person(age: 22);
  
  print("${person1.name != null ? person1.name : 'no name'}");
  print("${person2.name != null ? person2.name : 'no name'}");
}

class Person {
  String name;
  int age;
  
  Person({
    this.name,
    this.age
  });
}
```

**Console**

John

no name

Comment: The strange thing is, that it still doesn't work. population is a double value and it's null. I had to define it as double to avoid JSON decoding problems. Even with ?? it still jumps out of the line without using the alternative variable / String